# How to define the following make rule properly?

Tags: makefile, gtk

I would like to use a make file to generate a gresource file containing templates for my GTK project. I plan to use [Blueprints](https://jwestman.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/blueprint-compiler/) to generate the necessary XML files and then automatically generate the gresource file based on that. To do that I wrote the following make file:

```make
BP_SOURCE_DIR = mpyd-ui/bp
GRESOURCE_DIR = org/navi/mpyd
GRESOURCE_FILE = mpyd.gresource.xml
GRESOURCE_PREFIX = /org/navi/mpyd


COMPILED_BP_DIR = $(GRESOURCE_DIR)/templates
GRESOURCE   = $(subst .xml,,$(GRESOURCE_FILE))
BP_SOURCES  = $(notdir $(shell find $(BP_SOURCE_DIR) -name '*.bp'))     # window.bp player_controls.bp
COMPILED_BP = $(notdir $(BP_SOURCES:.bp=.ui))                           # window.ui player_controls.ui


gresource: $(COMPILED_BP)
    python3 generate_g_resources.py                 \
        $(GRESOURCE_FILE)                           \
        $(GRESOURCE_DIR)                            \
        $(GRESOURCE_PREFIX)                         \
        $(subst $(GRESOURCE_DIR)/,,$(COMPILED_BP))


%.ui: %.bp
    blueprint-compiler compile --output $(COMPILED_BP_DIR)/$@ $(BP_SOURCE_DIR)/$<


.PHONY: all
all: dirs gresource


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -r $(GRESOURCE_DIR)  ||:
    rm $(GRESOURCE_FILE)    ||:
    rm $(GRESOURCE)         ||:


.PHONY: dirs
dirs:
    @echo $(COMPILED_BP)    # window.ui player_controls.ui
    @echo $(BP_SOURCES)     # window.bp player_controls.bp
    mkdir -p $(GRESOURCE_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(COMPILED_BP_DIR)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and throws the following error:

```shell
make: *** No rule to make target „window.ui“, 
  needed by „gresource“. Stop.
```

This is confusing to me because I thought that the rule

```make
%.ui: %.bp
    blueprint-compiler compile --output $(COMPILED_BP_DIR)/$@ $(BP_SOURCE_DIR)/$<
```

would define how to make any file ending in `.ui` from a `.bp` with the same stem. What am doing wrong?

This is my folder structure, in case it has something to do with the error:

```
.
├── generate_g_resources.py
├── Makefile
├── mpyd-ui
│   ├── bp
│   │   ├── player_controls.bp
│   │   └── window.bp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
BP_SOURCES  = $(notdir $(shell find $(BP_SOURCE_DIR) -name '*.bp'))
COMPILED_BP = $(notdir $(BP_SOURCES:.bp=.ui))
```

So if you find, for example a file `mpyd-ui/bp/foobar.bp` then `BP_SOURCES` will be set to `foobar.bp` because you take the `notdir` of the files.  Then `COMPILED_BP` will bet set to `foobar.ui` (I don't know why you have another `notdir` since you already ran it on `BP_SOURCES`).

So make will try to build a file `foobar.ui` and it will see that your pattern rule matches the target pattern: `%.ui` with a stem of `foobar`.

So then it replaces the stem in the prerequisite pattern `%.bp` and gets `foobar.bp`.  Then make looks for the file `foobar.bp` but it doesn't exist (the file is named `mpyd-ui/bp/foobar.bp`, which is **not the same as** `foobar.bp`).  Also, make will try to build that target and it will not find any rules that can build it.  So, that pattern rule doesn't match and make ignores it and looks for another one.

Since no other pattern rule matches, make gives up and tells you there's no rule to make the target.

Basically, the problem is that by adding the `notdir` to your variables you are removing the ability of make to find your source files.

One way to solve this is to [use `VPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Search.html) to tell make where to look for source files, like this:

```
BP_SOURCES  := $(shell find $(BP_SOURCE_DIR) -name '*.bp')
COMPILED_BP := $(notdir $(BP_SOURCES:.bp=.ui))

VPATH := $(sort $(dir $(BP_SOURCES))
```

Comment: Note I'm using `:=` here: you should definitely prefer that especially when using functions like `shell` as it makes a big difference in performance.